# Desktop autostart not working

Tags: gnome, desktop

I have a CentOS 6 installation running Gnome.  Some time ago I noticed that my desktop autostart applications are no longer running.  For example in /etc/xdg/autostart I have vino set to run but it does not.  As well, in my ~/.config/autostart I have a test script which also never runs.

I don't know what broke this, but how would I go about finding why desktop autostart no longer works for user and system apps?